# Find consecutive identical elements in a row of a matrix in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, matrix, iteration

I want to iterate through the rows in a matrix and store the current value in each row. Then compare it to the next value. How can I do this?

I tried this

```
        bool ScoreRowPresent(RegularCandies[,] playingField)
        {
            bool score = false;
            int counter = 1;

            for (int row = 0; row < playingField.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                    for (int item = 0; item < playingField.GetLength(1); item++)
                    {
           
                        RegularCandies currentCandy = playingField[row, item];
                        int currentCandyValue = (int)currentCandy;

                        RegularCandies nextCandy = playingField[row, item+1];
                        int nextCandyValue = (int)nextCandy;

                        if (currentCandyValue == nextCandyValue)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }
                  }
            }

              if (counter == 3)
             { score = true; }

            return score;
        }
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code? Also you can’t directly cast the `RegularCandies` class object to `int`. Can you also provide this class definition as well? I think You will need to use some property of object instead of the object itself

Comment: I don't know if it has an issue or not.

Comment: … `playingField[row, item+1]` … is going to throw an index out of range error when `item = playingField.GetLength(1) – 1` … I suggest you change the inner `for` loop to… `for (int item = 0; item < playingField.GetLength(1) - 1; item++)` … You should show what the `RegularCandies` class looks like.

Comment: It's weird because I just had a look at the parts of my program, like separately, like apart from each other and I still can't find what the problem is.

Comment: There are several problems in the posted code. I noted one in my previous comment. Also, as noted… `int currentCandyValue = (int)currentCandy;` … looks odd and unless `RegularCandies` is a simple wrapper for an `int`, then this will not work and should probably cause an error. You should add what errors you are getting as I am confident you must be getting some errors. Please [edit] your question to add the `RegularCandies` class and any errors.